# How to download an image from a website that is saved under .aspx

Tags: python, html, image, web-scraping

Recently, I have been trying to learn how to web scrape in order to download all the images from my schools directory. However, within the elements, they are not storing the images under the img tag and instead have them ALL under this: background-image: url("/common/pages/GalleryPhoto.aspx?photoId=323070&width=180&height=180");

Is there anyway to get past this?? Never seen the .aspx before.

Here is the code that I am currently using to download images from websites.

```
import os, requests, bsf n4, webbrowser, random 
 
url = 'https://jhs.lsc.k12.in.us/staff_directory' 
  
res = requests.get(url)
try: 
    res.raise_for_status() 
except Exception as exc: 
    print('Sorry an error occured:', exc) 
 
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser') 
element = soup.select('background-image') 
 
for i in range(len(element)): 
    url = element[i].get('img') 
    name = random.randrange(1, 25) 
    file = open(str(name) + '.jpg', 'wb') 
    res = requests.get(url) 
    for chunk in res.iter_content(10000): 
        file.write(chunk) 
    file.close() 
 
print('done')
```

Comment: You need to add host (`'https://jhs.lsc.k12.in.us'`) to before `url`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will get you well on your way. You cannot *easily* do this just with `requests` because the site's content is loaded after the main page by JavaScript executing AJAX calls to load more content that updates the `DOM`. You really need to use a tool such as `[Selenium]`(https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) that will drive a web browser such as Chrome (or your choice) where you can wait for the elements you are looking for to appear. Even then it is not that straight forward. First, the photos are across multiple pages. The code below only processes the first page. You would then need to drive the browser to click on areas of the page to force the next page of photos to load.

Once the page content has loaded, I use Selenium's ability to find elements by its XPATH to retrieve all the `<span>` elements that contain the `style="background-image: url('some-value'"`. I then have to retrieve from these elements the `style` attribute and from that I have to look for the `background-image` url specification, which could be an empty string. Finally, I use a thread pool to retrieve all the URLs concurrently using a `request` `Session` object, which is more efficient. `BeautfulSoup` is not used at all. Finally, I do not use a `randrange` call to generate the name of the file since there could be a collision and you wouldn't want to attempt to store two images with the same name (and certainly not concurrently).

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import re


url = 'https://jhs.lsc.k12.in.us/staff_directory' 

def download_image(s, i, this_url):
    res = s.get('https://jhs.lsc.k12.in.us' + this_url)
    name = f'out_{i}.jpg' # don't use randrange because of possibility of duplicates
    with open(name, 'wb') as file: 
        for chunk in res.iter_content(10000): 
            file.write(chunk)  

    
def main():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("headless")
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    try:
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        driver.get(url)
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li/div[1]/div[1]/span')
        cnt = len(elements)
        if cnt == 0:
            print('No images found.')
            return
        with requests.Session() as s:
            MAX_THREADS = 100 # some suitable maximum number for you configuration
            N_WORKERS = min(cnt, MAX_THREADS)
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=N_WORKERS) as executor:
                futures = []
                for i in range(cnt):
                    style = elements[i].get_attribute('style')
                    m = re.search(r'background-image: url\("(.*?)"\)', style)
                    if m:
                        this_url = m[1]
                        if this_url != '':
                            futures.append(executor.submit(download_image, s, i, this_url))
                # wait for each task to complete:
                for future in futures:
                    try:
                        future.result()
                    except Exception as e:
                        print('task completed with exception:', e)
            print('done')
    except Exeption as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        driver.quit()

main()
```

**Version That Doesn't Use a Thread Pool**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import re


url = 'https://jhs.lsc.k12.in.us/staff_directory' 
   
def download_image(s, i, this_url):
    res = s.get('https://jhs.lsc.k12.in.us' + this_url)
    name = f'out_{i}.jpg' # don't use randrange because of possibility of duplicates
    with open(name, 'wb') as file: 
        for chunk in res.iter_content(10000): 
            file.write(chunk)   


def main():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("headless")
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    try:
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        driver.get(url)
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li/div[1]/div[1]/span')
        cnt = len(elements)
        if cnt == 0:
            print('No images found.')
            return
        with requests.Session() as s:
            for i in range(cnt):
                style = elements[i].get_attribute('style')
                m = re.search(r'background-image: url\("(.*?)"\)', style)
                if m:
                    this_url = m[1]
                    if this_url != '':
                        try:
                            download_image(s, i, this_url)
                        except Exception as e:
                            print('call completed with exception:', e)
            print('done')
    except Exeption as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        driver.quit()

main()
```

**Update to Download 6 Pages of Images (or All 120 Pages)**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import re


def download_image(s, file_no, this_url):
    res = s.get('https://jhs.lsc.k12.in.us' + this_url)
    name = f'out_{file_no}.jpg' # don't use randrange because of possibility of duplicates
    with open(name, 'wb') as file: 
        for chunk in res.iter_content(50000): # use larger chunksize
            file.write(chunk)  

file_no = 0

def download_page_images(s, executor, elements):
    global file_no

    futures = []
    for element in elements:
        style = element.get_attribute('style')
        m = re.search(r'background-image: url\("(.*?)"\)', style)
        if m:
            this_url = m[1]
            if this_url != '':
                file_no += 1
                futures.append(executor.submit(download_image, s, file_no, this_url))
    # wait for each task to complete:
    for future in futures:
        try:
            future.result()
        except Exception as e:
            print('task completed with exception:', e)

    
    
def main():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("headless")
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    try:
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        # first page:
        driver.get('https://jhs.lsc.k12.in.us/staff_directory')        
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li/div[1]/div[1]/span')
        cnt = len(elements)
        if cnt == 0:
            print('No images found.')
            return
        with requests.Session() as s:
            MAX_THREADS = 100 # some suitable maximum number for you configuration
            N_WORKERS = min(cnt, MAX_THREADS)
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=N_WORKERS) as executor:
                download_page_images(s, executor, elements) # first page elements
                #while True: # uncomment to download all the remaining pages or ...
                for _ in range(5): # to download up to just 5 more pages
                    # look for right arrow (more)
                    elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('fa-arrow-right')
                    if not elements: # this was the last page:
                        break
                    elements[0].click() # there is really only one right arrow
                    # look for next set of pictures on next page
                    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[4]/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li/div[1]/div[1]/span')
                    assert elements
                    download_page_images(s, executor, elements) 
            print('done')
    except Exeption as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        driver.quit()

main()
```

Comment: Just tried running this code but the images that it downloads are encoded or something. They can't be opened in any application. They all say that the format is not correct.

Comment: Sorry about that -- I was using the wrong URL in `download_image` but I have corrected this. What you had downloaded was HTML saying in essence that the URL could not be found.

Comment: I've updated the answer to download all or some of the pages of images (there are approximately 120 pages worth of images). There are up to N images per page so a pool of N threads is created (max 100 threads). It seems that N is 10. But the downloads could go faster if the elements for, let's say, 5 pages were read at a time, and we had a thread pool size of 50 and tried to download up to 50 images concurrently. I leave that change as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to take the image without work around is open the website using Firefox, Tools > Page Info > Media.

Under the Media section you will see the right full path from all medias including app loaded photos.

Copy the full address of the image and paste in the browser to save to your preferred location.